# Motherboards and hdd and ssd compatable

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard

I am currently looking for a motherboard that is either sata 6gb/s or sata express capable. Aswell as a SSD compatible. Does any body know of any motherboards that are capable of this? :(aka ssd and hdd compatable)

Comment: If it has SATA connector on it the motherboard can do both ssd and hdd.  There are some SSD that have special connectors on them, but you don't have to buy that kind of SSD.  Or are you saying you want to buy a NVM or similiar SSD?

Comment: Nope that was the answer i was talking about. Thank you. Why i couldn't find this b4 is bewildering. Thank you

Comment: I have made it an answer so you can mark it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has SATA connector on it the motherboard can do both ssd and hdd. There are some SSD that have special connectors on them, but you don't have to buy that kind of SSD. Or are you saying you want to buy a NVM or similiar SSD?